# How to fragment the viewing of a Bootstrap site using pagination?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have a list of  components whose contents are multiple choice questions formatted appropriately in bootstrap depending on the size of the device.
They are tests of about 200 questions, so the pagination (showing 10 - 20 questions on each page) would be very interesting.
I have tried using the class="pagination":

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" arial-label="Previous" href="#"> <---- I think here is the problem.
            <span aria-hidden="true">pag number</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is, once I have loaded the 200 test items, how can I make them appear 20 by 20 depending on the page that is being displayed? Bootstrap should be able to do it with the "pagination" class? I think that some value should be put in the href of the link of each page, but I don't know how to put it.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no JavaScript written in the library to make a pagination block function properly.

What you get is the HTML and CSS markup.

None of the examples in the documentation use real content so you're actually looking for a 3rd party library which doesn't involve AJAX if you're loading content all at once on the page.

If you do have an API or a json file to store data, you can use AJAX and update your resultset on every page call.

---

Speaking of which, this is how I've been doing this lately:

**Files:**

- `ns.cardloader.js` => drives your resultset with AJAX and renders results
- `ns.pagination.js` => updates your AJAX options and renders pagination
- `ns.fn.js` => some additonal functionality
- `ns.load.js` => a single loader file to create instances

Libraries:

- Handlebars - <strike>Mustache</strike> (templating)
- jQuery (oldsk00l ajax)
- Bootstrap (styling)
- npoint.io (json storage)

```js
/**
 * @author       [Tim Vermaelen]
 * @date         [2015-2022]
 * @namespace    [Ren.Pagination]
 * @requires     [jQuery, Ren]
 * @revision     [1.0]
 *
 * @doc https://github.com/janl/mustache.js
 */

/**
 * @param {Function} $ jQuery
 * @param {Object} tplEngine - Mustache library
 * @param {Object} ns namespace
 */
window.Ren = (function($, tplEngine, ns) {
  // 1. ECMA-262/5
  'use strict';

  // 2. CONFIGURATION
  const cfg = {
    cache: {
      container: '[data-class="pagination"]',
      pagerWrapper: '.pagination',
      pagerItem: '.page-item .page-link',
      pagerFirst: '.page-item.first .page-link',
      pagerLast: '.page-item.last .page-link',
      pagerPrev: '.page-item.prev .page-link',
      pagerNext: '.page-item.next .page-link',
      pagerSkip: '.page-item.skip .page-link'
    },
    classes: {
      pagerSkip: 'skip',
      pagerFirst: 'first',
      pagerLast: 'last',
      pagerPrev: 'prev',
      pagerNext: 'next',
      active: 'active',
      disabled: 'disabled',
      hidden: 'd-none'
    },
    data: {
      page: 'page-id',
      value: 'value',
      total: 'total',
      pageSize: 'page-size'
    },
    options: {
      pageSize: undefined, // undefined for data value
      maxPagerItems: 5,
      currentPage: 1,
      totalCount: undefined, // undefined for data value
      skip: 10 // undefined for auto calculated
    },
    tpl: {
      pagerItem: '#tpl-page-item',
      pagerFirst: '#tpl-page-item-first',
      pagerLast: '#tpl-page-item-last',
      pagerSkip: '#tpl-page-item-skip',
      pagerPrev: '#tpl-page-item-prev',
      pagerNext: '#tpl-page-item-next'
    }
  };

  /**
   * 3. CONSTRUCTOR
   * @param {Object} options : object literal like cfg
   */
  ns.Pagination = function(options) {
    this.settings = $.extend(true, {}, cfg, options);
    this.init();
  };

  // 4. PROTOTYPE
  ns.Pagination.prototype = {
    revision: 1.0,

    init: function() {
      this.cacheItems();

      if (this.container.length) {
        this.activate();
      }
    },

    cacheItems: function() {
      const {
        cache,
        data,
        options,
        tpl
      } = Object.assign(this.settings);

      // pager
      this.container = $(cache.container);
      this.pagerWrapper = this.container.find(cache.pagerWrapper);

      // tpl
      this.tpl = {
        pagerItem: $(tpl.pagerItem),
        pagerFirst: $(tpl.pagerFirst),
        pagerLast: $(tpl.pagerLast),
        pagerSkip: $(tpl.pagerSkip),
        pagerPrev: $(tpl.pagerPrev),
        pagerNext: $(tpl.pagerNext)
      };

      // options
      this.totalCount = options.totalCount || this.container.data(data.total);
      this.pageSize = options.pageSize || this.container.data(data.pageSize);
      this.maxPages = Math.ceil(this.totalCount / this.pageSize);
      this.maxPagerItems = this.maxPages < options.maxPagerItems ? this.maxPages : options.maxPagerItems;
      this.currentPageId = options.currentPage || 1;
      this.skip = options.skip || Math.floor(this.maxPages / this.maxPagerItems);
    },

    cachePagerItems: function() {
      const {
        cache
      } = Object.assign(this.settings);

      this.pagerPrev = this.pagerWrapper.find(cache.pagerPrev);
      this.pagerNext = this.pagerWrapper.find(cache.pagerNext);
      this.pagerFirst = this.pagerWrapper.find(cache.pagerFirst);
      this.pagerLast = this.pagerWrapper.find(cache.pagerLast);
      this.pagerItems = this.filterPagerItems(this.pagerWrapper.find(cache.pagerItem));
      this.pagerSkip = this.pagerWrapper.find(cache.pagerSkip);
      this.pagerSkipPrev = this.pagerSkip.eq(0);
      this.pagerSkipNext = this.pagerSkip.eq(1);
    },

    activate: function() {
      const {
        classes
      } = Object.assign(this.settings);

      if (this.assertOptions()) {
        this.destroy();
        this.renderPagination();
        this.cachePagerItems();
        this.togglePage(this.currentPageId);
      } else {
        this.container.addClass(classes.hidden);
        console.warn('ns.pagination.js: invalid options');
      }
    },

    /**
     * Assert valid options
     * @returns {Boolean} valid options
     */
    assertOptions: function() {
      const isValidTotalCount = !isNaN(this.totalCount);
      const isValidPageSize = !isNaN(this.pageSize) && this.pageSize > 0;
      const isValidMaxPagerItems = !isNaN(this.maxPagerItems);
      const isValidPageId = !isNaN(this.currentPageId) && this.currentPageId > 0 && this.currentPageId <= this.maxPages;

      return isValidTotalCount && isValidPageSize && isValidMaxPagerItems && isValidPageId;
    },

    /**
     * Filters pager items against an array of classes
     * @param {Object} pagerItems jquery object cache.pagerItems
     * @returns {Object} pager items who don't have a particular class
     */
    filterPagerItems: function(pagerItems) {
      const {
        classes
      } = Object.assign(this.settings);

      return pagerItems.filter(function(_idx, el) {
        const classList = [classes.pagerFirst, classes.pagerNext, classes.pagerPrev, classes.pagerLast, classes.pagerSkip];
        return !classList.some((c) => [...el.parentElement.classList].includes(c));
      });
    },

    /**
     * Render pagination based on templates
     */
    renderPagination: function() {
      const {
        classes
      } = Object.assign(this.settings);

      console.log('render pagination');

      if (this.maxPagerItems > 1) {
        const arr = [];
        let tplPagerFirst;
        let tplPagerPrev;
        let tplPagerItem;
        let tplPagerSkip;
        let tplPagerNext;
        let tplPagerLast;

        for (let i = 1; i <= this.maxPagerItems; i++) {
          if (i === 1) {
            tplPagerFirst = tplEngine.compile(this.tpl.pagerFirst.html());
            tplPagerPrev = tplEngine.compile(this.tpl.pagerPrev.html());
            tplPagerItem = tplEngine.compile(this.tpl.pagerItem.html());
            tplPagerSkip = tplEngine.compile(this.tpl.pagerSkip.html());
            arr.push(tplPagerFirst({
              id: i
            }));
            arr.push(tplPagerPrev({
              id: i
            }));
            arr.push(tplPagerItem({
              id: i
            }));
            arr.push(tplPagerSkip({}));
          } else if (i === this.maxPagerItems) {
            tplPagerSkip = tplEngine.compile(this.tpl.pagerSkip.html());
            tplPagerItem = tplEngine.compile(this.tpl.pagerItem.html());
            tplPagerNext = tplEngine.compile(this.tpl.pagerNext.html());
            tplPagerLast = tplEngine.compile(this.tpl.pagerLast.html());
            arr.push(tplPagerSkip({}));
            arr.push(tplPagerItem({
              id: i
            }));
            arr.push(tplPagerNext({
              id: i
            }));
            arr.push(tplPagerLast({
              id: this.maxPages
            }));
          } else {
            tplPagerItem = tplEngine.compile(this.tpl.pagerItem.html());
            arr.push(tplPagerItem({
              id: i
            }));
          }
        }

        this.pagerWrapper.append(arr);
        this.container.removeClass(classes.hidden);
      }
    },

    /**
     * Toggle visibility between page id's
     * @param {Number} id : page id (1|2|3|...|8)
     */
    togglePage: function(id) {
      this.updatePagerItems(id);
      this.updateSkip(id);
      this.updatePrevNext(id);
    },

    /**
     * Update the pager items state and data
     * @param {Number} id : page id (1|2|3|...|8)
     */
    updatePagerItems: function(id) {
      const {
        classes,
        data
      } = Object.assign(this.settings);

      if (this.maxPages >= this.maxPagerItems) {
        const end = this.maxPagerItems - 1;
        const offset = this.calcShiftOffset(id);
        const isLastPage = id === this.maxPages;
        const isFirstPage = id === 1;
        let activeId;

        for (let i = 1; i < end; i++) {
          let idx = offset + (i - 1);
          activeId = id === idx ? i : activeId;
          this.pagerItems.eq(i).data(data.page, idx).text(idx);
        }

        // update data
        this.pagerItems.eq(0).data(data.page, 1).text(1);
        this.pagerItems.eq(end).data(data.page, this.maxPages).text(this.maxPages);

        // update state
        this.pagerItems.eq(activeId).parent().addClass(classes.active);
        this.pagerItems.eq(0).parent().toggleClass(classes.active, isFirstPage);
        this.pagerItems.eq(end).parent().toggleClass(classes.active, isLastPage);
        this.pagerFirst.parent().toggleClass(classes.disabled, isFirstPage);
        this.pagerLast.parent().toggleClass(classes.disabled, isLastPage);
      }
    },

    /**
     * Calculates shift offset for variable amount of pager items
     * @param {Number} id : page id (1|2|3|...|8)
     * @returns {Number} offset to shift page indexes
     */
    calcShiftOffset: function(id) {
      const variablePagerItems = this.maxPagerItems - 2;
      const isVariablePagerItemsEven = variablePagerItems % 2 === 0;
      const variableMiddle = isVariablePagerItemsEven || variablePagerItems > 2 ? Math.floor(variablePagerItems / 2) : Math.ceil(variablePagerItems / 2);

      if (id >= this.maxPages - variableMiddle) {
        return this.maxPages - variablePagerItems;
      } else if (id <= variablePagerItems) {
        return 1 + variableMiddle;
      } else {
        return id - variableMiddle;
      }
    },

    /**
     * Updates skip state and data
     * @param {Number} id : page id (1|2|3|...|8)
     */
    updateSkip: function(id) {
      const {
        classes,
        data
      } = Object.assign(this.settings);
      const isMinMax = this.maxPages <= this.maxPagerItems;
      const shiftPrev = id - this.skip;
      const shiftNext = id + this.skip;
      const shiftCorrection = this.skip - this.maxPagerItems + 2;
      const isPrevBoundary = shiftPrev + shiftCorrection < 1 || isMinMax;
      const isNextBoundary = shiftNext - shiftCorrection > this.maxPages || isMinMax;

      // update state
      this.pagerSkipPrev.parent().toggleClass(classes.hidden, isPrevBoundary);
      this.pagerSkipNext.parent().toggleClass(classes.hidden, isNextBoundary);

      // update data
      this.pagerSkipPrev.data(data.page, shiftPrev < 1 ? 1 : shiftPrev);
      this.pagerSkipNext.data(data.page, shiftNext > this.maxPages ? this.maxPages : shiftNext);
    },

    /**
     * Updates previous and next state and data
     * @param {Number} id : page id (1|2|3|...|8)
     */
    updatePrevNext: function(id) {
      const {
        classes,
        data
      } = Object.assign(this.settings);
      const shiftPrev = id - 1;
      const shiftNext = id + 1;
      const isPrevBoundary = shiftPrev < 1;
      const isNextBoundary = shiftNext > this.maxPages;

      // update state
      this.pagerPrev.parent().toggleClass(classes.disabled, isPrevBoundary);
      this.pagerNext.parent().toggleClass(classes.disabled, isNextBoundary);

      // update data
      this.pagerPrev.data(data.page, isPrevBoundary ? id : shiftPrev);
      this.pagerNext.data(data.page, isNextBoundary ? id : shiftNext);
    },

    /**
     * Removes pager items and hides the container
     */
    destroy: function() {
      const {
        classes
      } = Object.assign(this.settings);

      this.pagerWrapper.empty();
      this.container.addClass(classes.hidden);
    }
  };

  // 4. GLOBALIZE OBJECT
  return ns;
})(window.jQuery, window.Handlebars, window.Ren || {});
```

```html
<nav aria-label="pagination" data-total="200" data-page-size="10" data-class="pagination">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <!-- js rendered -->
  </ul>
  <template id="tpl-page-item" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
                <li class="page-item"><button class="page-link" data-page-id="{{id}}">{{id}}</button></li>
            </template>
  <template id="tpl-page-item-first" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
                <li class="page-item first d-none"><button class="page-link" data-page-id="{{id}}">First</button></li>
            </template>
  <template id="tpl-page-item-last" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
                <li class="page-item last d-none"><button class="page-link" data-page-id="{{id}}">Last</button></li>
            </template>
  <template id="tpl-page-item-skip" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
                <li class="page-item skip"><button class="page-link">&hellip;</button></li>
            </template>
  <template id="tpl-page-item-prev" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
                <li class="page-item prev"><button class="page-link" data-page-id="{{id}}"><span>Previous</span></button></li>
            </template>
  <template id="tpl-page-item-next" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
                <li class="page-item next"><button class="page-link" data-page-id="{{id}}"><span>Next</span></button></li>
            </template>
</nav>
```

Check the demo for pagination. It works but without rendering results (some npoint.io thingy probably).
This is by far an ideal solution, but it goes to show how you cannot expect Bootstrap to solve your result rendering with pagination. There is no CSS only solution to this and if it does exists, its far from ideal.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/a8p2vcgq/)**

So I hope this gets you thinkering, perhaps use a 3rd party libary or even use this code. I've used it many times in production before.
Live example can be found at renson [dot] net (dealer search).

Comment: I do appreciate some feedback since I've spent more than 2hours trying to solve all the quircks inside cloud based editors just to show you this example. Also there was no time for me to change the data model to a quiz like thingy.
Hope you like it a little bit ^^

Comment: Heya! thank you for your very fast reply! Im trying to adapt your  code and for sure, up! I will feedback a bit better once Im done with the try!

Comment: Well, maybe I am adding React to the project, maybe is easier do this kind of things